# error TS2339: Property 'ɵbc' does not exist on type 'typeof import("/.../.../.../node_modules/@ngxs/store/ngxs-store")

Tags: angular, ngxs

In the package.json file of my project I have updated the @ngxs/store version to '^3.7.3' but when I compile I get this error:

```
Error: node_modules/@trec/app-modules/chat/src/chat-p/chat-p.module.d.ts:15:208 - error TS2339: Property 'ɵbc' does not exist on type 'typeof import("/home/xyz/ProjectsFE/FrontEndTraining/Angular/projectName/node_modules/@ngxs/store/ngxs-store")'.
```

Some informations:
Angular CLI: 12.2.17
Node: 12.20.0
Package Manager: npm 6.14.8

Any suggestions?

Edit 1:I realized that I have given little information. Sorry. :( This error comes from a file contained in the folder of a node_modules dependency.

Edit 2: This is package.json

```
{
  "name": "t-w-h",
  "version": "1.1.0",
  "author": {
    "name": "eH - F",
    "url": "https://a.b.eu/"
  },
  "license": "EUPL-1.1",
  "description": "T H web application.",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://a.f.eu/t/t-w-h.git"
  },
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "node": "^16.0.0",
    "npm": "^8.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "start:prod": "ng run app:serve:production",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build:dev": "ng build --configuration development",
    "build:prod": "ng build --configuration production",
    "build:staging-ragusa": "ng build --configuration staging-ragusa",
    "build:production-ragusa": "ng build --configuration production-ragusa",
    "build:production-7laghi": "ng build --configuration production-7laghi",
    "build:locale": "ng build --configuration locale",
    "release:patch": "standard-version --no-verify --release-as patch",
    "release:minor": "standard-version --no-verify --release-as minor",
    "docs": "compodoc -p tsconfig.app.json -d docs --theme gitbook --disableInternal",
    "test": "ng test",
    "test:ci": "ng test --watch=false --no-progress --browsers chrome_headless",
    "lint": "ng lint && stylelint './**/*.scss'",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "e2e:ci": "ng e2e --no-progress",
    "build:analyze": "webpack-bundle-analyzer dist/stats.json",
    "clean": "rimraf dist docs coverage node_modules",
    "prepare": "husky install"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@ag-grid-community/angular": "^26.1.0",
    "@ag-grid-community/client-side-row-model": "^26.1.0",
    "@ag-grid-community/core": "^26.1.0",
    "@angular/animations": "^12.2.12",
    "@angular/cdk": "^12.2.12",
    "@angular/common": "^12.2.12",
    "@angular/compiler": "^12.2.12",
    "@angular/core": "^12.2.12",
    "@angular/fire": "^7.1.1",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^12.0.0-beta.35",
    "@angular/forms": "^12.2.12",
    "@angular/localize": "^12.2.12",
    "@angular/material": "^12.2.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^12.2.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^12.2.12",
    "@angular/router": "^12.2.12",
    "@angular/service-worker": "^12.2.12",
    "@angular/youtube-player": "^12.2.12",
    "@capacitor/core": "^3.3.3",
    "@fullcalendar/angular": "^5.11.0",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "^5.11.0",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^5.11.0",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^5.11.0",
    "@fullcalendar/list": "^5.11.0",
    "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^5.11.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^6.1.6",
    "@mdi/angular-material": "^6.4.95",
    "@mdi/svg": "^6.4.95",
    "@ngxs-labs/actions-executing": "^0.1.9",
    "@ngxs/devtools-plugin": "3.7.3",
    "@ngxs/store": "^3.7.3",
    "@trec/api": "^5.0.16",
    "@trec/app-modules": "^3.0.21",
    "@trec/assets": "^1.7.3",
    "@trec/browser-compatibility": "^0.2.2",
    "@trec/components": "^2.0.0",
    "@trec/style": "^0.10.7",
    "animejs": "^3.2.1",
    "bpmn-js": "^8.8.3",
    "core-js": "^3.19.1",
    "d3-axis": "^3.0.0",
    "d3-scale": "^4.0.2",
    "d3-scale-chromatic": "^3.0.0",
    "d3-selection": "^3.0.0",
    "d3-shape": "^3.0.1",
    "d3-time-format": "^4.0.0",
    "date-fns": "^2.28.0",
    "datebook": "^7.0.7",
    "devmoji": "^2.2.1",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "firebase": "^9.7.0",
    "lib-jitsi-meet-dist": "^2.1.5",
    "ngx-panzoom": "^12.0.0",
    "pdfjs-dist": "^2.10.377",
    "rxfire": "^6.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.7",
    "swiper": "^6.1.0",
    "tslib": "^2.1.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^12.2.17",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "^12.6.1",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^12.6.1",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "^12.6.1",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "^12.6.1",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "^12.6.1",
    "@angular/cli": "^12.2.17",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^12.2.12",
    "@angular/language-service": "^12.2.12",
    "@capacitor/cli": "^3.3.3",
    "@commitlint/cli": "^14.1.0",
    "@commitlint/config-conventional": "^14.1.0",
    "@compodoc/compodoc": "^1.1.16",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^5.0.3",
    "@types/d3-axis": "^3.0.1",
    "@types/d3-scale": "^4.0.2",
    "@types/d3-selection": "^3.0.1",
    "@types/d3-shape": "^3.0.2",
    "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.10.5",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.10",
    "@types/node": "^16.11.6",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.18.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.18.0",
    "cz-conventional-changelog": "^3.3.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-header": "^3.1.1",
    "firebase-tools": "^9.1.1",
    "fuzzy": "^0.1.3",
    "husky": "^7.0.4",
    "inquirer": "^8.2.0",
    "inquirer-autocomplete-prompt": "^1.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^3.10.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^7.0.0",
    "karma": "^6.3.7",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^3.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "^4.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.4",
    "lint-staged": "^11.2.6",
    "npm-check": "^5.9.2",
    "prettier": "2.5.1",
    "protractor": "^7.0.0",
    "standard-version": "^9.3.2",
    "stylelint": "^14.1.0",
    "stylelint-config-prettier": "^9.0.3",
    "stylelint-config-standard-scss": "^2.0.1",
    "typescript": "~4.3.5",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^4.5.0"
  }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: can you please attach your package.json file?

Comment: Hi @batman567! I have attached package.json file. Thank you :)

Comment: Have the same issue after upgrading @ngxs/store to ^3.7.4 and Angular to v14

Answer (score 1):

Dropping @ngxs/store down to version 3.6.2 seems to remove the error, but that version is more than two years old.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's the same issue, but we had a similar error. In our case the issue was caused by conflicting versions of `ngxs-store`. In the `package.json` we used the recently released, ivy compatible version 3.8.0 but some of our dependencies were still referring to version 3.7.6. Bumping the ngxs-store to the latest version in the subdependencies solved it. Might be useful for others who ran into this problem.